# Webbrick shuts down on its own

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, terminal, localhost

When I try to lauch webbrick from my terminal using rails server, This is what I get and webbrick shuts down, what could be the problem.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
```

Following the shutdown I get this huge error which absolutely makes no sense to me.

```
/Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:229:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:116:in `normalize_options!'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:64:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1443:in `new'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1443:in `add_route'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1422:in `decomposed_match'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1403:in `block in match'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1394:in `each'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1394:in `match'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:601:in `map_method'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:562:in `get'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/Sites/recrea8/config/routes.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `eval_block'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:319:in `draw'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/Sites/recrea8/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/Sites/recrea8/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/Sites/recrea8/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/Sites/recrea8/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/Sites/recrea8/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/Sites/recrea8/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /Users/Fulcrum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

This is my route.rb

```
Recrea8::Application.routes.draw do


  resources :sessions
  resources :users
  resources :categories
  resources :characters
  resources :industries
  resources :nationalities
  resources :personalities
  resources :project_types
  resources :projects

  get 'logout', 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'users#new'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Comment: It seems to be that a mistake is in your routes.rb file. Can you show it too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change lines:

```
#get 'logout', 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
```

And

```
#root 'users#new'
root to: 'users#new'
```